# Rotate legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I wish to rotate a ggplot2 legend 90°

From

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl)
```

[image]

to produce

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl)
p + scale_colour_continuous(guide = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal", title.position = "top",
                             label.position="bottom", label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = 0.5,
                             label.theme = element_text(angle = 90))) + 
      theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9))
```

Ref: [ggplot docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guide_legend.html)

[image]

Comment: Do you know why using the `guide =  guide_legend(...` seems to change the key from continuous to discrete?

Comment: that's because legends are discrete - you want `guide_colorbar`.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl) + theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To be totally correct, I think you need to use `label.theme` as well as `title.theme` inside `guide_legend`. I think it's better with `title.position = "left"`.

(copy-pasting parts of previous solutions)

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl) +
    scale_colour_continuous(guide = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal", title.position = "left", title.theme = element_text(angle = 90),
                             label.position="bottom", label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = 0.5,
                             label.theme = element_text(angle = 90))) + 
      theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9))
```